# Issue with Solana wallet by sending funds to Associated Token Metadata account

Tags: cryptocurrency, solana, wallet-connect

I sent a token to an "associated token metadata" account from my main Solana wallet. Now the tokens are allocated to a sub-account whose owner is the associated token metadata. I can't get access to this account, so my question is, is there a way to recover those funds? I have tried deleting it in another account but it doesn't get your funds back to the main wallet (at least not instantantly). Any other ideas? Solana developers would be appreciated to answer about this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to recover these funds for the moment, but this is an open issue that has tripped up many people.  You can follow the progress of the issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2248